# std::cout not properly printing std::string created by reinterpret_cast of unsigned char array

Tags: c++, cout, stdstring, reinterpret-cast

I have an `unsigned char` array that stores 1 byte hex characters and I would like to do bitwise operations on these values.

After using reinterpret_cast to get them into a string (with the idea of using std::stringstream and std::bitset to do the necessary operations), I tried printing the string to see what the contents were. Rather strangely, I noticed that std::cout did not give the expected result, however using printf did!

Here is a quick example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    unsigned char my_txt[] = {
        0x52, 0x5f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x7e, 0x29, 0x33, 0x74, 0x74, 0x73, 0x72, 0x55
    };
    unsigned int my_txt_len = 12;

    std::string my_std_string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(my_txt), my_txt_len);

    for (size_t i=0;i<my_txt_len;i++)
        printf("%02X ", my_std_string[i]);      // Works fine!
    printf("\n");

    std::cout << my_std_string << std::endl;    // Bad stuff happens :S

    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
52 5F 73 68 7E 29 33 74 74 73 72 55     // Expected
R_sh~)3ttsrU                            // ??
```

Determined to find a solution, I tinkered around for a while - guessing that reinterpret_cast may be causing this behaviour. I eventually found that doing this:

```
std::cout << std::hex << (int)my_std_string[0] << std::dec << std::endl;
```

produced the desired result, at least for the first character anyway. Iterating through a loop gave the correct values for the other 11 bytes as well.

Can someone explain why this happens with std::cout and not with printf? At first, I thought that maybe I needed to cast it back to `unsigned char` but doing this had no effect. Why does casting to `int` give the correct output?

Is it safe to do bitwise operations on the values stored in a string after using reinterpret_cast as I have used? It has occurred to me that all of this may be rather pointless as I believe I can just do binary math on the unsigned char's directly, no? Advice here would be appreciated.

For those who are curious, I am trying to write a custom C++ console application (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine) to interface with a CAN-USB adapter using the vendor's API. I expect to receive (as part of larger 'receive frame' structs) 8 byte unsigned character arrays with values in hex and I need to process these values to get usable data for my application. This processed data is then being stored in a protocol buffer for further interpretation in matlab.

Sorry if this seems like a silly question - I'm coming from a hardware background and haven't done any serious programming in a while (first post on SO!).

Comment: What was the string you expected? This seems to be correct according to the ascii table.

Comment: You do not store "1 byte hex characters". You store bytes. The base of the digits you wrote in a literal to enter those values into your program source code is not relevant. Further, your `printf` and `std::cout` approaches are not even close to the same, so complaining that they have different results seems somewhat unfair on the programming language in question.

Comment: You're confusing representations and values. You may want to see these [two](http://superuser.com/questions/693440/why-does-an-exe-file-not-appear-as-ones-and-zeros-in-a-text-editor-such-as-notep) [questions](http://superuser.com/questions/369231/why-dont-you-see-binary-code-when-you-open-a-binary-file-with-text-editor) related to this issue. In short, both `52 5F 73 68 7E 29 33 74 74 73 72 55` and `R_sh~)3ttsrU` are valid representations of the `{ 0x52, 0x5f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x7e, 0x29, 0x33, 0x74, 0x74, 0x73, 0x72, 0x55 };` byte sequence.

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit and milleniumbug. Yeah, it seems I'm a bit rusty with the basics haha

So I assume it is safe, then, to do binary math (bit masking, adding bytes together, etc.) on the values stored inside the string?

Comment: @KnightsValour: Sure why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
std::cout << my_std_string << std::endl;    // Bad stuff happens :S
```

to

```
for( std::size_t i = 0; i < my_txt_len ; i++ )
{
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(my_std_string[i]) << " " ;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

A `std::string` is a representation of a string, not purely an array of bytes. Therefore, passing it to `std::cout` will show a string. Your `printf` is printing individual values of your `unsigned char` array. The stl equivalent of this is an `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

You need to add the `static_cast<unsigned>()`. Otherwise `std::cout` will print each `unsigned char` value as a `char` ascii character. The output will be `R _ s h ~ ) 3 t t s r U`. You have to prevent this conversion by implicitly telling it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @tillaert! Can you explain why it needs to be cast as an int (as opposed to an unsigned type)?

Comment: It seems that static_casting as either <int> or <unsigned> produces the same answer. Well, as long as the value can be operated on safely, I guess I'm okay. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm switching to Python, just for show:

```
>>> s = [ 0x52, 0x5f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x7e, 0x29, 0x33, 0x74, 0x74, 0x73, 0x72, 0x55]
>>> ''.join(map(chr, s))
'R_sh~)3ttsrU'
```

I mean, these are the ASCII equivalents for your bytes. And that's what the constructor of `std::string` does: take an array of nul-terminated characters, and build a string from there. Your `reinterpret_cast` casts between `unsigned char*` and `char*`, and that is one of the few safe things it does.

What you probably want is to build a string with the text representation of the integers. For that use `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase;
for (size_t i=0;i<my_txt_len;i++)
    os << std::setw(2) << my_txt[i] << " ";
std::string txt = os.str();

std::cout << txt;
```

With `printf` you didn't have this problem because the type of the argument in `printf` is set by the format string, in your case `%X` means read as integer and write in hexadecimal. If you pass a `char/unsigned char` it is automatically promoted to integer (but beware! most types are *not* promoted that way, only `chars` and `shorts`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and code! I suppose the output isn't strictly necessary for me - as I just needed to be sure that the values were being correctly put in the string with reinterpret_cast. As long as I can do binary math on these values and then store them  - I think I'll be okay. But, I'll keep your code handy as a reference.

Comment: @KnightsValour: No problem. But if you want to store `unsigned chars`, consider using `std::vector<unsigned char>`. `std::string` is for text, not raw bytes, and it will get you into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify, I'm using a vendor's library that provides structs as the container for message frames. In this struct, the data bytes are stored in an array with this declaration: uint8_t data[8]. Given this, I need to be able to do binary math on the bytes, and other SO posts have mentioned using std::stringstream and std::bitset. This is why I originally thought of using std::string as a container - as eventually, this information will be serialized using a protocol buffer. Are there better approaches that meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain why this happens with std::cout and not with printf? At first, I thought that maybe I needed to cast it back to unsigned char but doing this had no effect. Why does casting to int give the correct output?

You told `printf` to output in hex, so it output in hex. What's the mystery exactly?

Comment: Correct - I thought that adding std::hex in the cout statement would do the equivalent. As @tillaert pointed out, a string isn't an array of bytes and it seems I was expecting it to be. Thanks for the clarification!